# execute javascript after ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem with ajax that Javascript not render after page load.
I have this code:

```
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("fb-root").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "like.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {

            FB.init({
                appId: 'XX',
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function (o) {
                if (!o && o.status) return;
                if (o.status == 'connected') {
                    // USER IS LOGGED IN AND HAS AUTHORIZED APP
                    window.onload = loadXMLDoc();
                } else if (o.status == 'not_authorized') {

                    window.onload = loadXMLDoc();
                } else {
                    // USER NOT CURRENTLY LOGGED IN TO FACEBOOK
                    document.write("connect3")

                }
            });

        };

        (function () {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
    </script>
```

the like.php file contain

```
<?php echo  <script src='/facebook/src/like.js'></script>; ?>
```

When a user is logged in facebook the ajax load but script doesn't execute.
The script at body section are checked and work well.
Where is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Chrome console give 'Invalid application ID: The provided application ID is invalid.'

Comment: I'm not that equipped with jquery/ajax, but maybe a `$(document).ready()` is needed?

Comment: @PRPGFerret: jQuery isn't being used, at least within the code provided above...

Answer (score 1):

[Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

The link above addresses this issue. To load a script tags contents you may wish to simply inject a new script tag using dom manipulation rather than using innerHTML. An example is provided for you in the async fb portion of the script you posted.

```
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.async = true;
e.src = '/facebook/src/like.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
```

This has the same effect assuming the php code doesn't do any other operations. Also it is worth pointing out that your current implementation will remove the `all.js` file from the dom (since you set innerHTML).

Comment: I'm quite new to this.
Could you explain how to do it, please?

Comment: I tried this. it's only add script tag, but the script isn't execute

Answer (score 1):

echo in like.php doesn't contains quotes.
Should be

```
<?php echo "<script src='/facebook/src/like.js'></script>"; ?>
```

Also FB.getLoginStatus is not fired

Tip: Use firebug if you use Firefox (or other debug tools if other browsers) and use console.log()

Likely solution: replace contents of function loadXMLDoc with

```
jQuery('#fb-root').load('like.php');
```

Comment: you right. it contains... i didn't copy paste it and forgot only here

Comment: if you're asking about jQuery('#fb-root').load('like.php');, it should be inside function loadXMLDoc: 
 
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        jQuery('#fb-root').load('like.php');
    }

Comment: I've added only this code:  jQuery('#fb-root').load('like.php');
now it loads script but all page is blank. Only the script has been loaded